# How to query a property bag entity type in EFCore5?

Tags: .net-core, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

In EFCore5, implicit tables are saved as `Dictionary<TKey, object>` sets, knows as [Property Bag Entity Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties#property-bag-entity-types). However, I cannot figure out how to create a LINQ query with a Where() clause that compiles for MySQL for such a property bag entity type.

For example, this code successfully retrieves the `IQueryable` reference to an intermediate table (generated by EFcore5's implicity many-to-many feature) given the `ISkipNavigation`:

```
ISkipNavigation nav = // some many-to-many relationship

IQueryable<Dictionary<string, object>> intermediateTable = 
  context.Set<Dictionary<string, object>>(nav.JoinEntityType.Name);
```

And this code successfully retrieves all the entries in the intermediate table:

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>> joins = await intermediateTable.ToListAsync();
```

In the resulting `List`, each `Dictionary` has just one key/value (representing the row).

However, I cannot figure out how to add a `.Where()` clause to the LINQ query which will compile:

```
joinTable.Where(d => d.Keys.First() == "foo").ToList();
joinTable.Where(d => d.Keys.Any(k => k == "foo")).ToList();
```

The error is:

> Translation of member 'Keys' on entity type 'MachinePartMachineProfile (Dictionary<string, object>)' failed. This commonly occurs when the specified member is unmapped. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'

I do not wish to do client-side parsing for performance reasons (the join table will be to big).

I note that the type reported by the error is `MachinePartMachineProfile (Dictionary<string, object>)`. Some investigation showed that [these types are being generated](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/b970bf29a46521f40862a01db9e276e6448d3cb0/src/EFCore/Metadata/Conventions/ManyToManyJoinEntityTypeConvention.cs#L129-L130) based upon the static `Model.DefaultPropertyBagType` (which is a `Dictionary<string, object>`). But despite staring at the EFCore code base, I cannot discern how to correctly query such a default property bag type.

I am using MySQL as my database, if it is relevant.

Answer (score 2):

You can index the dictionary directly, with knowledge of the column name.

Working example would be:

```
joinTable.Where(d => d[columnName] == "foo").ToList();
```

And for the sake of completeness, if you have an `ISkipNavigation` instance, you can infer these keys as follows:

```
string foreignKey = nav.ForeignKey.Properties.First().GetColumnBaseName();
string localKey = nav.Inverse.ForeignKey.Properties.First().GetColumnBaseName();
```